# Can pystache tell me if a pattern is not defined?

Tags: python, mustache

I have the following script:

```
import pystache
d = {
    'MSG' : 'bye'
}
print pystache.render('I say {{MSG}} {{THIS_IS_UNDEFINED}}', d)
```

Which prints:

```
I say bye
```

But I actually want pystache to raise an exception because there is an undefined pattern. In my real code, things are more complicated, so getting hints about what patterns are undefined would be very valuable.

Is it possible to configure pystache for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `Renderer` with `missing_tags="strict"`:

```
>>> import pystache
>>> pystache.Renderer(missing_tags="strict").render("I say {{MSG}} {{THIS_IS_UNDEFINED}}", d)
KeyNotFoundError: Key u'THIS_IS_UNDEFINED' not found: first part
```

You could define your own function `strictrender`:

```
def strictrender(s, d):
    renderer = pystache.Renderer(missing_tags='strict')
    return renderer.render(s, d)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know pystache. I can suggest a helper instead - using `format()`:

```
def render(fmt, d):
    fmt.replace('{{', '{').replace('}}', '}').format(**d)
    return pystache.render(fmt, d)
```

and perhaps you can do `pystache.render = render`.

It is not a perfect solution, of course.

Comment: Thanks, but no. Pystache (mustache implementation in python) is more feature rich than that. My example was deliberately very simple.